# HOw to use Jmeter Variable in REgex?

Tags: regex, jmeter

[image]My regular expression is looks like this "\u003e(\d+)\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd colName=\"FacilityName\" style=\"text-align:left\"\u003eFAC${JMETERVARIABLE}"

This is not working in Jmeter.Somebody please help me on this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Please explain what the behavior is...

Comment: Reference name is null

Comment: You probably need to escape `\$\{JMETERVARIABLE\}`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem of getting regex to work when the returned text contains '\u003e' etc instead of the normal characters, and in the end I inserted a Beanshell sampler to put the variable ${whatever} together with the rest of the regex string, then passed the entire string as a variable into the regular expression extractor (REE). My jmeter script is on a different machine so please forgive the lack of screenshots.

I got this from another SO answer which i can't now find (do please someone insert the reference if you know it), but in brief it looks something like this (in the large 'Script' window of the Beanshell sampler)

```
String s = "your regex phrase ${jmeter variable}";
vars.put("RegPhrase",s);
```

and then in the REE for 'Regular Expression' field you just put ${RegPhrase}

It also has the advantage that the final RegPhrase appears as a variable in the debug PostProcessor, so you can copy and paste it into the RegEx field of the http request output in the view results tree, to test the phrase works with your data, then tweak as required.